# More about $\liminf$ and $\limsup$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I know that for a given sequence of real numbers, the limit superior (lim sup) of this sequence is the smallest real number that is "eventually" larger than every number in the sequence. In other words, no matter how far out you go in the sequence, you can always find a number that is smaller than or equal to the limit superior. It is the largest value that the sequence "approaches" (without necessarily reaching it).

On the other hand, the limit inferior (lim inf) of a sequence is the largest real number that is "eventually" smaller than every number in the sequence. No matter how far out you go in the sequence, you can always find a number that is larger than or equal to the limit inferior. It is the smallest value that the sequence "approaches".

Sometimes, the limit superior and limit inferior are the same, in which case we say the sequence has a limit. But in other cases, they can be different, or one or both of them can be infinite, which helps us understand sequences that oscillate or grow without bounds.

However, I feel that there is something that I do not understand because sometimes I do not understand why it was used in some proofs. Could you please explain more about this concept?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "In other words, no matter how far out you go in the sequence, you can always find a number that is smaller than or equal to the limit superior." Not quite. The sequence $$0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,\cdots$$ has no limit superior (or it is $\infty$), yet your "in other words" would imply that $0$ works. At least if your alternate take is an attempt at defining the $\limsup$ intuitively. Also note that `\limsup` and `\liminf` are perfectly fine MathJax commands.

Comment: I don't know of an example at the moment, but I'm pretty sure that sometimes it can be convenient to prove the existence of a limit ("finite limit", or "finite or infinite limit") by working separately with lim-inf and lim-sup, in much the same way that for functions of a real variable it sometimes can be convenient to prove the existence of a limit by working separately with the left limit and the right limit. Also, lim-inf and lim-sup are useful for describing certain types of behavior of a sequence when the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Your "question" needs more focus.